# React event-handler shows the same index value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

have a simple React component that displayes a character and should call a handler when clicked, and supply a number. The component is called many times, thus displayed as a list. The funny thing is that when the handler is called, the supplied index is always the same, the last value of i+1. As if the reference of i was used, and not the value.

I know there is a javascript map function, but shouldn't this approach work too?

```
const charComp = (props) => {
    return (
        <div onClick={props.clicked}>
            <p>{props.theChar}</p>
        </div>
    );


  deleteHandler = (index) => {
    alert(index);
  }

 render() {
    var charList = []; // will later be included in the output
    var txt = "some text";
    for (var i=0; i< txt.length; i++)
    {
        var comp = 
        <CharComponent
          theChar = {txt[i]}
          clicked = {() => this.deleteHandler(i)}/>;
        charList.push(comp);      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because by the time you click on a letter, `i` is already 9 and it will remain 9 since the information is not held anywhere.
If you want to keep track of the index you should pass it to the child component `CharComponent` and then pass it back to the father component when clicked.

```js
const CharComponent = (props) => {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    props.clicked(props.index);
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={clickHandler}>
      <p>{props.theChar}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
var comp = (
  <CharComponent theChar={txt[i]} index={i} clicked={(index) => deleteHandler(index)} />
);
```

A little [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-cdn-xnjfi) for ya

Comment: Thank you man, I understood there was something with storing the index!